# Can't click button with selenium PhantomJS and get the data

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from booking. However, even though if I open the page from a browser I can see prices,  when I try to download a page with its source code with python, the request return a page with buttons: 'Show prices' instead of the prices.

The source code of the page, around the button, is:

```
data-click-store-id="sr-compset-2128695"
data-et-click="customGoal:YPNdKNKNKZJUESUPTOdJDUFYQC:1
customGoal:YPNdKNKNKZAMUVdFePOdXeRe:1"
data-et-focus="customGoal:OTfdASFOQJNDYBWfBQVT:1" target="_blank"
<span class="b-button__text"> Show prices </span>
```

I based this code on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230605/python-get-request-returning-different-html-than-view-source),

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

web_site='https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=376363&label=bdot-1gtfXe7K0wVduEQU2KBU*QS144456159570%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap21%2C093%2C000%3Aac%3Aap1t1%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atiaud-146342138710%3Akwd-334108349%3Alp1008736%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm&lang=en-gb&sid=316b1ca4ddb0b74abc941811e1a769db&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Faid%3D376363%3Blabel%3Dbdot-1gtfXe7K0wVduEQU2KBU%252AQS144456159570%253Apl%253Ata%253Ap1%253Ap21%252C093%252C000%253Aac%253Aap1t1%253Aneg%253Afi%253Atiaud-146342138710%253Akwd-334108349%253Alp1008736%253Ali%253Adec%253Adm%3Bsid%3D316b1ca4ddb0b74abc941811e1a769db%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Rome%2C+Lazio%2C+Italy&ssne=Apia&ssne_untouched=Apia&checkin_monthday=28&checkin_month=10&checkin_year=2017&checkout_monthday=31&checkout_month=10&checkout_year=2017&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&genius_rate=1&from_sf=1&ss_raw=rom&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=en&dest_id=-126693&dest_type=city&search_pageview_id=18384c2ba57602b5&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=18384c2ba57602b5&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(web_site)
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot1.png')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# click proceed
proceed = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "\nShow prices\n")))

proceed.click()
# wait for the content to be present
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "workskin")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()
```

[This is a saved screenshot by phantomJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19erm.jpg)

Comment: "Can't lick button" xD brb dying

Comment: hehe thankyou any idea?

Comment: Please update the question with the exact error you see. If the problem is that the element does not exist, have you tried using partial link text instead or other locators?

Comment: In your interested web_site, where is the element that you are trying to click? (Show prices)

Comment: You can now see the screenshot that phanomJS "see", the button is in:span class="b-button__text"